# php strtodate with three vars to check to change status in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, strtotime

hi i am working on a project and my mind has drawn a blank so i put it to the world to help me out.

I have a MySQL Database like this
the start date of the item, notice date is one week from end, then the end date when its expired

```
+table+
|id|   start  |  notice |   end    |status|
|01|2013-09-01|2013-9-23|2013-10-01|Active|
....
```

PHP

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, 
DATE_FORMAT(`start_date`,'%d-%m-%Y') as fmt_start_date,
DATE_FORMAT(`notice_date`,'%d-%m-%Y') as fmt_notice_date,
DATE_FORMAT(`end_date`,'%d-%m-%Y') as fmt_end_date 
FROM `$table` ORDER BY `fmt_start_date` ASC "); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $start = strtotime($row["fmt_start_date"]);
    $notice = strtotime($row["fmt_notice_date"]);
    $end = strtotime($row["fmt_end_date"]);
    $current = strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));

    if( $notice >= $current && $end <  $current){
        mysql_query("UPDATE `$table` SET  `status` =  'Notice' WHERE  `id` ='{$row["id"]}';"); 
    } elseif ( $end <= $current ){
        mysql_query("UPDATE `$table` SET  `status` =  'Expire' WHERE  `id` ='{$row["id"]}';");
    } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `$table` SET  `status` =  'Active' WHERE  `id` ='{$row["id"]}';");
    }
}
```

what i want it to do is as the dates pass through it changes the status of it so when its in the notice week the status changes to notice, when it has passed the end it expired and when its hasn't passed these dates it stays active.

i know how i want it done but my mind has drawn a blank on the method for this. 
please help me internet.

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) *(no longer supported/maintained)* and will be [**removed**](http://j.mp/11j2t6j) in the future. You should update your code using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure future functionality.

Comment: i know that just used mysql_ as the example to make it easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
if ($current < $notice){
//has not reached notice (Active)

} elseif ($current < $end){
//has not reached end but has reached notice (Notice)

} else{
//has reached end (Expired)

}
```

Comment: perfect so atleast i was on the right track with it .. thanks @schmidt382

Answer (score 1):

At first:

About mysql functions you've been warned.

For getting UNIX time stamp from MySQL database you should use MySQL function UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), for example:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`field_name`) FROM `table_name`;
```

For getting time stamp of the beginning of the day better use "strtotime('today')".

In answer to your question: in your case you do not need to use so many PHP. Enough to make two MySQL requests:

```
$current = strtotime('today');
mysql_query("UPDATE `$table` SET  `status` =  'Notice' WHERE  `notice` < FROM_UNIXTIME($current);");
mysql_query("UPDATE `$table` SET  `status` =  'Expire' WHERE  `end` < FROM_UNIXTIME($current);");
```

Comment: this is what i was using first but as it needs to change other items in sql as well it was not used.

Comment: in that case better use something like `UPDATE some_table t1, table t2 SET t1.column1 = 'some value' WHERE t2.status = 'Expire';`. Of course after first two requests.